# Error when exporting skeletal animation from Blender

Tags: three.js

I have a problem with the export skeletal animations from blender 2.63. The model and the animation was done in 3d max, and exported in a blender collada.

Screenshot settings exporter: clip2net.com/s/2jP4m

Screenshot blender, Pose Position: clip2net.com/s/2jP89

Live demo version, with exports Pose Position: 213.219.244.158/boneanim/index2.html

Screenshot blender, Rest Position: clip2net.com/s/2jPax

Bug, Rest Position: clip2net.com/s/2jPc9

Live demo version, with exports Rest Position: 213.219.244.158/boneanim/index.html

Files:

Blender file: 213.219.244.158/boneanim/blender.blend

Collada file: 213.219.244.158/boneanim/run.DAE

Json file, Pose Position: 213.219.244.158/boneanim/untitled2.js

Json file, Rest Position: 213.219.244.158/boneanim/untitled.js

*P.S. Forgive stackoverflow does not allow me to insert links.*